# How i can solve this get_dummies() error?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

i want change my data to numerical data
and i use this code

```
import pandas as pd

cars = pd.read_csv("caterogical data.csv")
ohe_cars = pd.get_dummies(cars[['Car']])

print(ohe_cars.to_string())
```

at first, I tidied up the data because I thought this data could not be read but still got an error

like this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 PS C:\Users\BAGAS Laptop> & "C:/Users/BAGAS Laptop/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/python.exe" "e:/BELAJAR CODING/Belajar coding2023/.vscode/python machine learning6"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\BELAJAR CODING\Belajar coding2023\.vscode\python machine learning6", line 139, in <module>
    ohe_cars = pd.get_dummies(cars[['Car']])
                              ~~~~^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\BAGAS Laptop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3767, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns._get_indexer_strict(key, "columns")[1]
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\BAGAS Laptop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 5877, in _get_indexer_strict
    self._raise_if_missing(keyarr, indexer, axis_name)
  File "C:\Users\BAGAS Laptop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 5938, in _raise_if_missing
    raise KeyError(f"None of [{key}] are in the [{axis_name}]")
KeyError: "None of [Index(['Car'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems that you have put two many brackets.
Try: `ohe_cars = pd.get_dummies(cars['Car'])`

Please provide a reproductible with your datasets if it's not working so that I can help you at best.

Comment: import pandas as pd

cars = pd.read_csv("E:\BELAJAR CODING\Belajar coding2023\.vscode\caterogical data.csv")
ohe_cars = pd.get_dummies(cars['Car'])

print(ohe_cars.to_string())        I try it

Comment: the code still error

Comment: PS C:\Users\BAGAS Laptop> & "C:/Users/BAGAS Laptop/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/python.exe" "e:/BELAJAR CODING/Belajar coding2023/.vscode/python machine learning6"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\BAGAS Laptop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3653, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Comment: File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 147, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 176, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 7080, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 7088, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'Car'